RDP from Windows to Debian box - Black screen?
just bought a small thinkcenter and installed debian on it. I'm trying to get RDP working from my Windows desktop but whenever I connect with RDP I get a black screen. I'm confident the connection is working because if I type the wrong password I get refused, and when I do the right it connects. I also get logs in the xrdp logs.
All the firewall stuff, etc is working
I'm using Cinnamon
On the actual machine, I am not signed into the account that I'm trying to RDP with
security_layer=rdp in xrdp.ini
I tried putting cinnamon-session in the .xsession file
The remote connection just sits on black screen until I quit it. I think it is in fact connecting. It's just not rendering anything?
